# Reviewing Linux logs in Arcsight

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to use ArcSight to review Windows and Linux logs for security issues. The logs are already in ArcSight, so I'm just writting some simple ArcSight queries to pull out the information needed. For Windows, I can just search on event IDs for what I want, such as 4624 for a successful logon, or 4625 for an unsucessful logon. However, apparently Unix, which I know nothing about, doesn't have anything like an event ID. If I do a search on "login" I at least get some hits that look like the system is logging for logins. If I search for "Logout" or "Logoff" I get nothing. Is there anyway to easily find records for specific events in Unix other than doing text searches until you find something that seems to be what you want? Is there at least a document of the main logging messages for redhat linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for events with a `type` of `USER_LOGIN` and `USER_LOGOUT` in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for remote logins, e.g. with ssh.

Use of `sudo` and other user/role changes will be logged with a `type` of `USER_START` and `LOGIN`, and `USER_END`. See also `USER_AUTH` for authentication attempts.

The `type` of `LOGIN` also records local GUI console logins, but as far as I can see console logout isn't recorded in the audit log. It's still available in the usual places, e.g. `last`.

There are many other types of data recorded in the audit log. You should look through it to see if there are other items of interest to you.

---

Before you try to use ArcSight you should take a little time to become familiar with the system logs and the sorts of information they contain.

On a Red Hat system the logs you will use most frequently are:

- `/var/log/messages` contains general system, service and application logs. These are generated by either the kernel or the applications themselves.
- `/var/log/secure` contains logs mostly relating to authentication and authorization. These are also generated by either the kernel or the applications themselves.
- `/var/log/audit/audit.log` contains detailed security audit events for a wide variety of system activity. All of these are generated by the Linux kernel.

The systemd journal also contains all of this data, and more. ArcSight doesn't seem to support the journal (or I couldn't find out about it), but it [does support the audit log](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/ArcSight-Connectors/SmartConnector-for-Linux-Audit-File/ta-p/1588811). This must be configured separately from a syslog connector. To get the most detailed information you should use a log analyzer which supports importing directly from the journal and is actually doing so.